# please help me to define a perl regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, web-crawler

I'm new to everything. Please help. I'm trying to crawl every

```
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
```

in a webpage. I want to catch the /v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk part. (Knowing that the

```
<div class="name"><a href="/v/
```

part is fixed) So I wrote the regular expression (can make you laugh):

```
~m#<div class="name"><a href="(/v/.*?)">#
```

It will be very helpful if you correct my stupid code.

Comment: Regexing html is covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [robust HTML parser](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) (see http://htmlparsing.com/ for why):

```
use strictures;
use Web::Query qw();
my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html(<<'HTML');
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
<div class="name"><a href="/v/name/idlike123123ksajdfk">name</a></div>
HTML

my @v_links = $w->find('div.name > a[href^="/v/"]')->attr('href');
```

Comment: You should improve your answer a little bit to ensure `@links` contains just links starging with `/v/` as stays in OP's post.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of Perl modules that extract links from HTML. [WWW::Mechanize](https://www.metacpan.org/module/WWW%3a%3aMechanize), [Mojo::DOM](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aDOM), [HTML::LinkExtor](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aLinkExtor), and [HTML::SimpleLinkExtor](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aSimpleLinkExtor) can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Web scraping with Mojolicious is probably simplest way to do it in Perl nowadays

http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Web_scraping

Comment: Sorry for posting this as "answer" but I cannot comment others, to put this link to Brian's post instead.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It looks neat. Pity that I don't have a chance to try it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should **not use regex for parsing HTML**, as there are many libraries for such parsing.

Daxim's answer is good example.

---

However if you want to use regex anyway and you have your text assigned to `$_`, then

```
my @list = m{<div class="name"><a href="(/v/.*?)">}g;
```

will get you a list of all findings.